# How to statically link libcurl with dev c++?

Tags: c++, libcurl, static-linking

Recently I am trying to link libcurl with dev c++ statically.I linked all the .a files except libcurldll.a file which came from libcurl and I defined CURL_STATICLIB . But I received some linker errors. Then I searched google for the solution of this  linker error, there I found that "libwsock32.a" should be linked. And finally I linked libwsock32.a. But I am still receiving different linker errors... Errors are like....

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_set_optionA' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_initA' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_set_optionA' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_simple_bind_sA' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_search_sA' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_first_entry' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_get_dnA' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_first_attributeA' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_get_values_lenA' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_value_free_len' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_memfreeA' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_next_attributeA' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_memfreeA' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_next_entry' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_err2stringA' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_unbind_s' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_msgfree'
```

And so on.........

I also searched for this linker errors in google but nothing found. Plzzzz give me a solution why I am receiving this linker errors????

Comment: Please read the description of [dev-c++](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info), and then use a different IDE.

Comment: If you build curl from source, you should have the curl-config utility. Run it with the --libs flag to get the compiler switches you need to link in the necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows and Mingw gcc or g++, add
 **libwldap32.a** to linker, 
literally it is a
 **-lwldap32** 
linker option.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to link with [ldap](http://www.openldap.org/). You should also consider not using Dev-C++, and use an actively developed, high quality IDE like [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers-includes-incubating-components/indigor)

Comment: As your suggestion I have started to using code::blocks ide.... But I am still receiving same linker errors....... What should I do now????

Comment: Changing IDE is unlikely to change the outcome of compilation (The IDE and the compiler are separate programs). Did you install [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/)? (Sorry to ask again, when it is already in my answer, but it is the only thing that I can think of)

Comment: Also, are you following the instructions in the MingW32 section of [these docs](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html)? Which version of GCC are you using?